# File locked only if copy/paste, not if cut/paste

Tags: c#, file-io, ioexception

I'm monitoring a folder for new files, and when the new file is present I read (and save in a txt) the file as following:

```
FileStream file = File.Open(this.filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
StreamReader reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(file);
string text = reader.ReadToEnd();
reader.Close();
```

If I copy/paste in the folder the source file, I receive an IOExcpetion that tells me that the file is used by another process.
If I cut/paste in the folder, all works.
Moreover locking problem happens also If I copy (but also cut in this case)/paste the file from another machine into the monitored folder.

Do you have an idea about what is happening?

There is a safer way to access to the file in order to avoid this type of locks?

Thanks!

Comment: How are you monitoring the folder..Show us the code..Are you using FileSystemWatcher?

Comment: I'm using FileSystemWatcher (inside a wrapping class in order to monitor more than one folder)

Comment: most probably there's a conflict with your `FileSystemWatcher` ! show us the code

Comment: sure! I used this code: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/271669/Using-FileSystemWatcher-to-monitor-multiple-direct

Comment: Sounds like your copy process is locking the file and file system watcher is trying to access it before its completed.  What I normally implement with a FileWatcher is a little method that loops and trys to open the file and if its inside of a try catch you can catch the exception return false and try again till it works then you can access your file and process.

Comment: @Bearcat9425: I thougth the same, but why the behaviour is different If I cut/paste? And what about if I cut/paste from another machine? Could be related to the missing FileShare option?

Comment: I would say from another machine its just more due to the time it takes for the file to make it over and the copy process holding the file hostage.  Its good practice when working with Files to add logic to make sure a file is fully accessible before performing any processing.  FileSystem is pretty fast in its access of the file so your process logic starts dang near immediately so you want to make sure its not locked.

Comment: @Bearcat9425 So do you think the event is raised when the file is created and then sometimes before it is "ready"?

Comment: I tried with a huge file, and I saw that the created event (and also changed one) are raised immediately, even if the file needed other couple of minutes to be completely copied. Any possibility to have an event raised at the end?

Comment: No that event is raised the moment it happens.  Not sure if anyway to delay it. I suggest you take a look and implement something like what I have below in order to solve this. The solution below will allow you to halt processing till the file is done copying and all processes have released it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a little snippet I do to ensure the file is finished copying or not in use by another process.

```
 private bool FileUploadCompleted(string filename)
    {
        try
        {
            using (FileStream inputStream = File.Open(filename, FileMode.Open,
                FileAccess.Read,
                FileShare.None))
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        catch (IOException)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Then you can implement this before your process logic

```
while (!FileUploadCompleted(filePath))
{
    //if the file is in use it will enter here
    //So you could sleep the thread here for a second or something to allow it some time
    // Also you could add a retry count and if it goes past the allotted retries you
    // can break the loop and send an email or log the file for manual processing or
    // something like that

}
```